# Convert EXR to BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, openexr

I need to read an EXR image file and to load it in a BufferedImage, but java doesn't support this file type by default. Doing some google search, as well does not help too much, because I have not found a working solution.
Could someone help me please to solve this problem?

Comment: You'd need to find or to create an `ImageReader` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html) and register it for the EXR file format.

Comment: IlmImf (one of the libraries supporting EXR file format) is bundled in OpenCV. It is available for both Java and Android, so you may give it a try.